# how to post parameter from html page to servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee

This is my  Dem.html page can not excuted properly when i click on "okeeee"button not event is genereated

```
<form action="http://localhost:7000//DemoS/MyServlet" method="post">
</form>
<input type="text" name="e">
<input type="text" name="p">
<input type="submit" value="Okeeeeeeee">
```

The post servlet method:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  String e=request.getParameter("e");
  String p=request.getParameter("p");out.println("  <HEAD><TITLE>A Servlet</TITLE></HEAD>");
  out.println("  <BODY>");
  out.println(", using the POST method abhinav   hiii"+e+""+p);
  out.println("  </BODY>");out.println("</HTML>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs must be enclosed between the form tags:

```
   <form action="http://localhost:7000//DemoS/MyServlet" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="e">
      <input type="text" name="p">
      <input type="submit" value="Okeeeeeeee">
   </form>
```

Comment: Don't forget to improve score and vote for the best answer for the best answer for each of your question, to keep the stack overflow spirit...